# Range RemoveDuplicates Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the range.RemoveDuplicates function to remove duplicates from the first column and the second column.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Array(1), xlNo

    Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Array(2), xlNo
End Sub
```

Why does the second call, to remove the duplicates from the second column fail with a Invalid Procedure Call or Argument?

Comment: `Range("B:B")` only has *one* column.

Comment: with only one column being used both `Array(1)` and `Array(2)` should just be `1` as the column reference is relative and no need to use an array when there is only one column

Comment: @ScottCraner - I'd upvote if you made that an answer.

Comment: Oh, the columns array is a relative reference.  Well that works. Thanks.